# Handling Trusted Application Status Dialog Event in BlackBerry after installing a new Application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

Whenever I install my Application on the Blackberry device I get a prompt asking "Trust Application" with yes, no and help options. If Yes is selected everything works fine, if I choose No I get other prompts with Allow and Deny again and again due to permission issues as my application uses Location Services. 
What I want is whenever the Trusted Application dialog comes and after Users selection of yes or no I want to show a Alert or Information telling "Please select YES in trusted application dialog for Correct working of this Application, if you selected No then you can restart the App and select YES". This is just a toast or information that appears before loading the Home or main screen of the application if Trusted Application dialog appears. How do I handle this case, can anyone help me out in solving this issue....

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Blackberry Webworks SDK, you can use the System API to find out the available permissions (and other information about the system) 
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.system.html#.hasPermission

You should be able to do a check against those parameters and show the dialog box warning users that they have not provided permission.

If you want to find some sample code, check out: https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/kitchenSink

Comment: Thanks Clarke, you were talking about the Appliations using WebWorks SDK but I need it to be done for BB Apps developed using Java SDK.Can I get any help regarding that??